# Разница между ::std::ios_base::app и ::std::ios_base::ate

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

В чём разница между `::std::ios_base::app` и `::std::ios_base::ate`?

Эта программа выводит то же самое, что и для `::std::ios_base::app`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::std::stringstream ss{"1", ::std::ios_base::in bitor ::std::ios_base::out bitor ::std::ios_base::ate};
    ::std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
    ss << "2";
    ::std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
    ss << "3";
    ::std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: @user7860670 судя по тому что там написано, app должен перед каждой записью << делать перенос, как он и делает, а вот почему ate делает то же самое, хотя должен только при открытии переносить непонятно

Comment: Возможно, если в файл пишут сразу несколько потоков/приложений, это на что то повлияет?

Comment: в вашем примере позиция нигде не изменяется, а вообще установка позиции (после конструктора) работает при создании потоков в бинарном режиме (который имеет смыл с файловыми потоками)

Comment: @user7860670 добавил ss.seekp(0); после записи двойки, всё равно нет разницы между app и ate, хотя для app по идее должен был вывод не отличаться

Comment: потому что он не в бинарном режиме и бинарный режим работает для файловых потоков и не совместим с текстовм

Comment: @user7860670 то есть для текстового app и ate одно и то же, а для бинарного нет?

Comment: по идее в текстовом нельзя просто так менять позиции

Comment: первый устанавливает позицию в конец, *при записи*, а второй _ сразу при создании объекта.